# Parallel LOAD DATA to different memory tables very slow compared to single one

Tags: mysql, parallelism

I'm using a fairly simple bash script to execute mysql load data infile to 11 different MEMORY engine tables.

Example:

```
load.sh
echo "start $@ $(date)"
mysql -p"mypass" -e "use db; set bulk_insert_buffer_size = 1024 * 1024 * 256;
   alter table testLoadData$@ disable keys; 
   LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/db/mysql_secure/clearedhalf$@.log' INTO TABLE testLoadData$@ FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' lines terminated by '\n'; 
   alter table testLoadData$@ enable keys;"

echo "end $@ $(date)"
```

Now, `multi.sh`:

```
for i in {0..10}
do
    /usr/local/bin/bash /root/loadinfile/load.sh $i &
done
wait
```

On a single table this runs about 12 seconds for a 200Mb file with around 1 million lines in it.

However when I run 10 of them in parallel it looks like they are locking at some point, mysql only uses one core and HDD is used about 6Mb/s (we do have raid10 ssd on this box), and it takes about 2 minutes for some reason.

My question is - do I need to change/tweak some settings to allow mysql use all of my resources and perform all of these loads simultaneously?

Comment: Try it with InnoDB instead of MEMORY.

Comment: (That's 11 in parallel.)

Comment: Hey @RickJames ! yes you are correct that's 11, and I've tried Innodb and it had worse performance even with all the needed tweaks.

Comment: Check your table names and their sizes.  Did the start/end times overlap as expected?

Comment: All tables are filled in correctly and there are no problems, all tables are done almost simultaneously  which is suggesting that they're all processed at the same time but mysql is not using all of the server resources